# How does Sequential feature selection work

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, feature-selection

I recently watched a Youtube tutorial on Sequential feature selection and ran the below code for identifying best features in my dataset (of 977 rows, 77:23 class proportion, binary classification and linear regression)

```
 sfs = SFS(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1,class_weight='balanced_subsample',max_depth=5,max_features='log2',n_estimators=300),
             k_features=15,
             forward=True,
             floating = False,
             verbose=2,
             scoring='f1',
             cv=5,
             n_jobs=-1
             ).fit(ord_train_t,y_train)
```

And I got the below output (shown at the bottom)

my question is

a) Is the feature numbers 1, 2 and 3 correspond to the order of the columns in the input dataframe? For instance, if instead of K=15, if I chose K=7, would the SFS only try the **1st 7 features** (columns) in our dataset or would it try the **best 7 features** for our dataset?

b) How can I find the best subset of features? whether it is 5,7 or 9 automatically?

```
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  16 out of  20 | elapsed:   25.0s remaining:    6.2s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  20 out of  20 | elapsed:   30.3s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:01:35] Features: 1/15 -- score: 0.524463839508817[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  14 out of  19 | elapsed:   17.1s remaining:    6.0s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  19 out of  19 | elapsed:   22.9s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:01:58] Features: 2/15 -- score: 0.5563816840436558[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  13 out of  18 | elapsed:   17.6s remaining:    6.7s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:   22.7s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:02:21] Features: 3/15 -- score: 0.6022317115639352[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  11 out of  17 | elapsed:   16.2s remaining:    8.8s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  17 out of  17 | elapsed:   20.4s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:02:42] Features: 4/15 -- score: 0.5993100974277444[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  10 out of  16 | elapsed:   17.1s remaining:   10.2s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  16 out of  16 | elapsed:   17.4s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:02:59] Features: 5/15 -- score: 0.6011398328191893[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   8 out of  15 | elapsed:    8.3s remaining:    7.2s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  15 out of  15 | elapsed:   15.7s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:03:15] Features: 6/15 -- score: 0.6186241525595746[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   7 out of  14 | elapsed:    8.2s remaining:    8.2s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  14 out of  14 | elapsed:   15.3s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:03:30] Features: 7/15 -- score: 0.6182522183455019[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   5 out of  13 | elapsed:    8.4s remaining:   13.6s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  13 out of  13 | elapsed:   14.8s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:03:45] Features: 8/15 -- score: 0.6293119815507875[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 out of  12 | elapsed:    8.2s remaining:   16.4s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:   14.2s finished
    
    [2022-02-28 12:04:00] Features: 9/15 -- score: 0.6225708168642952[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of  11 | elapsed:    8.5s remaining:   38.7s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   8 out of  11 | elapsed:    9.0s remaining:    3.3s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  11 out of  11 | elapsed:   13.8s finished

[2022-02-28 12:04:13] Features: 10/15 -- score: 0.6102147632876342[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   7 out of  10 | elapsed:    8.3s remaining:    3.5s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:   12.3s finished

[2022-02-28 12:04:26] Features: 11/15 -- score: 0.6109474505140013[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 out of   9 | elapsed:    8.3s remaining:   10.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:   12.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:   12.1s finished

[2022-02-28 12:04:38] Features: 12/15 -- score: 0.603023643023643[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   8 | elapsed:    8.4s remaining:   14.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   8 out of   8 | elapsed:    8.5s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   8 out of   8 | elapsed:    8.5s finished

[2022-02-28 12:04:47] Features: 13/15 -- score: 0.6220595801873146[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 out of   7 | elapsed:    7.5s remaining:    5.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   7 out of   7 | elapsed:    7.6s finished

[2022-02-28 12:04:54] Features: 14/15 -- score: 0.5976115979520211[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   6 | elapsed:    7.2s remaining:    7.2s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   6 out of   6 | elapsed:    7.3s finished

[2022-02-28 12:05:02] Features: 15/15 -- score: 0.588869366480916
```